# When I exit the spark shell all the dataframe data is gone. Is this normal ?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I'm learning Apache Spark. I'm loading CSV data into a dataframe. This can take about 5 minutes (a lot of data). When I exit the spark-shell and log back into the spark-shell the data is gone.  Is this normal behavior ? I can't find anything about this in the documentation. How can I persist the data between sessions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is expected, similarly in ipython shell if you create an array it wont be stored once you exit the shell. To store it, you can do:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.range(10).map(l => l.toInt).toDF() // create a mock data frame
df.write.parquet("outputfile.parquet") // save it to a file, consider s3 with s3://yourbucket/yourfile.parquet if it is too large
```

Once you restart your shell, you can get your dataframe back with:

```
spark.read.parquet("outputfile.parquet").collect
```

Comment: Thank you for the sanity check!

Comment: why do you suggest to call `collect`? If you want the DataFrame back, just use  `spark.read.parquet("outputfile.parquet")`

Comment: I added it so that when copy-pasted this snipplet illustrates that it works on this small example. I hope one would know that you should not collect a big dataframe :)